# Unable to start spring-boot application after configuring spring-session-data-redis

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

After configuring `spring-session-data-redis` in a demo spring-boot project, `bootRun` task fails with the following message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method redisTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool', 'redis.clients.jedis.Jedis'
    - Bean method 'redisConnectionFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.lettuce.core.RedisClient'

Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' in your configuration.
```

---

**What I've done (a.k.a. steps to reproduce):**
1. Used [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to create a [Gradle with Java and Spring Boot 2.1.0 M1 + Web dependency] project.
2. Followed the [Spring Session - Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html) instructions to configure Spring Session. More specifically:
 - added `compile 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis'` 
   to build.gradle's dependencies block
 - configured the store type by adding `spring.session.store-type=redis` to `application.properties` file
 - configured the connection
   properties (in `application.properties` file): `spring.redis.host`,
   `spring.redis.password` and `spring.redis.port` with relevant values
3. Executed `./gradlew bootRun` from the root of the project and received the above error

---

**Questions:**
1. As far as I'm understand from the error message, `RedisConnectionFactory` failed to load because it can't find neither Jedis nor Lettuce drivers. Shouldn't `spring-session-data-redis` bring one of those drivers by default?
2. How to resolve this issue in case I want to use the Jedis driver?
3. How to resolve this issue in case I want to use the Lettuce driver?

Comment: 1. No. 2 or 3 include them yourself. The sample uses `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` as well, this pulls in a driver by default.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. The guide itself doesn't mention `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`, nor explicit driver dependency. Also, it seems that this is a behavior change - I'm able to run `bootRun` using spring-boot's `1.5.16.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` version flawlessly without explicit driver dependency.

Comment: The instruction are incorrect and are out of sync with the sample application to which they link. It [has a dependency on spring-boot-starter-data-redis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/samples/boot/redis/spring-session-sample-boot-redis.gradle#L8).

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks. Is there a recommended way for pulling the Lettuce driver in: implicitly by adding `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` dependency, or explicitly by adding `io.lettuce:lettuce-core` dependency?

Comment: I would use the starter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1.**
As [@M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51742342/unable-to-start-spring-boot-application-after-configuring-spring-session-data-re?noredirect=1#comment90448069_51742342) mentioned, `spring-session-data-redis` (version 2.1.0.M1) doesn't pull Jedis or Lettuce drivers.

**2.**
Add the latest Jedis driver as explicit dependency:

```
dependencies {  
    // ...  
    compile 'redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0'  
}
```

**3.**
Either add `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` (which pulls in Lettuce driver) or the latest Lettuce driver as explicit dependency:

```
dependencies {  
    // ...  
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'  
    // OR
    compile 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.0.5.RELEASE' 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 implementation of `RedisConnectionFactory` are comes with `spring-session-data-redis`

(1) lettuce (default) - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/789

(2) Jedis

Since lettuce & Jedis dependency are optional u have to have explicit dependency. u can put dependency to either one of it. (u can have both but Spring redis implementation stater used lettuce as a default implementation)

Example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>x.x.x</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>x.x.x</version>
    </dependency>
```